# NoReverse Match at "" Reverse for "" with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}'

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to display a list of links to a list view in Django but I keep getting a "NoReverse Match" error.

Template

```
{% for posts in all_posts %}
<a href="{% url 'blog:blog_single' posts.slug %}">{{posts.title}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Views

```
from blog.models import Posts
from main_site.views import LayoutView

class BlogView(LayoutView, generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    model = Posts
    context_object_name = 'all_posts'
```

Blog / urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.SingleView.as_view(), name='blog_single'),
    url(r'^$', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog_home'),
)
```

Project /urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
)
```

slug is property in my model set to models.SlugField() and if I output as just {{posts.slug}} it shows up so I know it's not empty. I have a similar link set up in a different app in the project that's working fine (exact same set up -- url 'namespace:name') so I'm not sure what's causing this to break.

The full error is:

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/

Reverse for 'blog_single' with arguments '(u'test-slug',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'blog/(?P<slug>\\w+)/$']
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because you have bad url pattern.

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', views.SingleView.as_view(), name='blog_single'),
```

is expecting \w+ (that is any letter character, number character or underscore). But you are supplying it with a text containing a dash ("-").

So you need change your slug or url pattern to be like:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.SingleView.as_view(), name='blog_single'),
```